# Removing from array has side-effects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am making a form to create orders. The input fields are dynamic and can be added with a button.

Now after every row there is a delete button, which should delete the row.

For this this I made the **delRow()** function. It works because the row gets deleted, unfortunately the values of the rows underneath it are removed as well, but the input fields stay in place. I can't seem to figure out why.

Template:

```
<form>
      <div class="form">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
              <td>
                <input class="product" ng-model="row.product[$index]" placeholder="{{productPlaceholder}}" type="text">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input ng-model="row.amount[$index]" type="number" min="0">
              </td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-functionality btn-danger btn-del" ng-click="delRow($index)">x</input>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-success btn-add" ng-click="addRow()">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="main-buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-create" ng-click="createOrder()">Create</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="cancelOrder()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.orderNew', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/order/new', {
    templateUrl: 'order-new/order-new.template.html',
    controller: 'OrderNewCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('OrderNewCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http, $log) {

  $scope.$log = $log;
  $scope.message ="test";

  $scope.rows = [{}];
  $scope.counter = 1;
  $scope.productPlaceholder = 'Product';


  $scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.rows.push({});
    $scope.counter++;
  }

  $scope.delRow = function(index) {
    if ($scope.rows.length < 2) { return; }

    $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
  }

  $scope.cancelOrder = function() {
    $location.path('/orders');
  }

  $scope.createOrder = function() {
    var data = $scope.fields;
    alert(data);
    //$post('/path_to_server', obj);
  }

  $http.get('orders.json').then(function(data) {
    $scope.orders = data;
  });

});
```

Comment: I think you're using the splice function wrong, it should be $scope.rows.splice(0, index)

Comment: Nope that removes everything

Comment: Hmmm try posting a jsFiddle with the code in it so that I can test it

Comment: Try wrapping the `splice` in a `$scope.$evalAsync(function () { ... })` call. Or try adding `$scope.$apply()` after the `splice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<input ng-model="row.product[$index]" type="number" min="0">
```

You should do this:

```
<input ng-model="row.product" type="number" min="0">
```

Because you are deleting the rows the index reference is getting thrown off. Instead of using a index reference you can just just place the values directly to a attribute of the object.

I whipped up a working pen here:

http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/gmyBRo?editors=1011